# Linear form arising in expected value of empirical variance of non-independent variables

Tags: variance, matrix, linear-algebra, quadratic-form

Consider a normal vector $Y \sim \mathcal N(\mu, V)$ with $\mu \in\mathbb R^n$ and $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. I am interested in the expected value of
$$ {1\over n-1} \left( Y'Y - {1\over n} (\mathbb 1' Y)^2 \right),$$
where $\mathbb 1$ is a vector of ones. This is the empirical variance computed on $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ as if they were independent.

We have $E(Y'Y) = (\mu' \mu) + \text{trace}(V)$ and 
$$E\left((\mathbb 1' Y)^2 \right) = (\mathbb 1'\mu)^2 + \text{var}(\mathbb 1'Y) =  (\mathbb 1'\mu)^2 +  \mathbb 1' V\mathbb 1,$$
thus the expected value is
$${1 \over n-1}\left( \mu'\mu - {1\over n} (\mathbb 1'\mu)^2\right) + { n \,\text{trace}(V) -   \mathbb 1' V\mathbb 1 \over n(n-1)}.$$

The left-hand part is $0$ when $\mu \propto \mathbb 1$, ie all $Y_i$ have same expected value.

The right-hand part is a linear form of square matrices. It can be also written as "mean of diagonal elements minus mean of off-diagonal elements". It measures in some sense how much is $V$ dominated by its diagonal. Of course, if $V = \sigma^2 I_n$, its value is $\sigma^2$.

Did you meet this linear form before? Has it a name? Has it nice known properties?

Comment: You ask about some measure of "diagonal dominance" of a matrix. Some links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317044/measure-of-diagonal-dominance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392491/measure-of-how-much-diagonal-a-matrix-is, googling will give a lot more